# Is there a "security fail forum / website" with lessons learned?

Tags: defense, system-compromise

I have done some searching, and cannot seem to find this.  Does anyone know of a "security fail forum" that lists embarrassing and / or damaging results from lack of security practices?  I would like it to serve to educate everyone on how important computer security really is, kind of like the drunk driving horrors video is meant to discourage drunk driving.  It would be nice if it also pointed out what could have been done differently, or the lesson learned.  Here are a couple examples:

***Example 1:***

**Security Fail:**

Someone let their former friend use their computer, but they did not log out of their bank account before hand.  This "friend" transferred all the funds of the owners bank account to their own bank account!  The owner lost $10,000, quite a costly lesson!

**Lesson(s) Learned / Preventative Measures:**

- Do not let your friends use your computer under your user account
- If you do let your friends use your computer (especially under your account), make sure you watch what they are doing
- Log out of websites when you are done on them
- Lock your computer or log off when you leave it

Following any of these practices would have prevented the incident.

***Example 2:***

**Security Fail:**

My website is being repeatedly Distributed Denial of Serviced (DDoS)!  What can I do to prevent it?

**Lesson(s) Learned / Preventative Measures:**

NONE YET - Awaiting good suggestions!

Comment: If you let your friend use your computer and they steal $10k from you, I'd argue that that's an issue with your choice of friend, not what you're letting them do.

Comment: So, an IT Security version of [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)? If there isn't one, we should make one.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/badsecurity/ but it's empty

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yes, that is pretty close to what I am looking for, with lessons learned associated with it.  Perhaps users could provide lessons learned, or what could have been done to prevent it.

Comment: There is a security fails Twitter account : http://twitter.com/secfails

Comment: @AndréDaniel Nice find! One of the tweets links to this: http://www.secmeme.com/ which also has some nice posts.

Comment: Also there is [Plaintext Offenders](http://plaintextoffenders.com) for real world examples on how not to store passwords.

Comment: FailyMonster on Twitter reports on these type of incidents. https://twitter.com/failymonster

Comment: @S.L.Barth That is actually pretty close to what I am looking for.  Now if it had preventative measures along with it, that would be great!

Comment: For the example 2, here's a one word easy solution : Cloudflare.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Great find for mitigating DDoS attacks!  I don't know how good this solution is (never used it), but it does at the very least have a good description of how various DDoS attacks work here: https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos

Comment: I like your original idea, but this is a really bad example of a "lesson learned".  Personally I don't have friends that might steal 10,000 from me, and don't consider this to be an information security error, but a friend picking error.  TLDR;  Pick a better sample question, like a SQL Injection attack, etc.

Comment: @Jonathan You are probably (implicitly) using Cloudflare several times a day without even knowing.

Answer (score 2):

The Department of Homeland Security offers Open-Source Infrastructure Reports though daily emails, and in tandem with this you may sign up for US-DHS-CERT updates on vulnerabilities.  I don't know of a singular source with this information.

http://www.dhs.gov/dhs-daily-open-source-infrastructure-report

https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/current-activity

For a comprehensive list, such as the one you are looking for, cross-referencing will more than likely be necessary.

For the specific format of information you are looking for, the IRC site may have this type of information, though you would be essentially entering the 'wolves den.'